# Tricky integral over the real line

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve the integral 
$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)\cosh(\sinh(x))}dx$

Integration by part and substitution seem not to work. I think it should be done by contour integration, but I can't find the right path because of the singularity of $log(1+z^2)$ as $z\rightarrow i$.

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: The non-analiticity of $\log(1+x^2)$ is not the only problem, $\cosh(\sinh x)$ has a lot of zeroes in the complex plane, are you sure about the denominator?

Comment: I see your point. Contour integration would be problematic because of the evaluation of the residues at $z_{n_1n_2}$ s.t. $\cosh(\sinh(z_{n_1n_2}))=0$, $\left(n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\right)$. But the expression I posted is correct. I also tried to find a substitution in order to simplify the denominator, but all those I have found give very hugly expressions as the argument of the logaritm.